# Составить запрос Mysql

Tags: mysql, orm, laravel

Нужно составить вот такой запрос.

```
DB::table('work')
            ->select(DB::raw('FROM_UNIXTIME(date, \'%Y %D %M %h:%i\') AS unique_date'))
            ->where('moderator', $moderator)
            ->whereNotIn('unique_date', $data)->get();
```

Он генерируется в

```
select from_unixtime(date, '%Y %D %M %h:%i') as unique_date from `work` where `moderator` = 1 and `unique_date` not in (2015 27th August 08:25, 2015 27th August 08:34)
```

В данном случае выходит ошибка:

> Unknown column 'unique_date' in 'where clause'

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Нужно делать выборку по ассоциации столбца. Можно пример запроса на чистом sql, это не критично.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `'unique_date'` в условии поставить `'FROM_UNIXTIME(date, \'%Y %D %M %h:%i\')'`. И еще почему то даты в массиве без кавычек прописаны `(2015 27th August 08:25, 2015 27th August 08:34)` (должно так быть `('2015 27th August 08:25', '2015 27th August 08:34')`)

Comment: @Visman, кавычки не отображаются, но они как бы есть, просто на выход дается так. А по поводу первого, просто не делать ассоциацию, а приводить date?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что в условии не использовать имя поля генерируемого самим запросом, а использовать ту формулу на основе которой оно генерируется.

Comment: @Visman, О, спасибо огромное! Переведи комментарий в ответ, отмечу.

Comment: @ArtieLay имя поля генерируемого самим запросом можно использовать только в  having

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, почитаю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мой ответ из комментариев** В условии запроса вместо имени генерируемого самим запросом поля используйте формулу на основе которого формируется это поле. То есть вместо

```
        ->whereNotIn('unique_date', $data)->get();
```

используйте

```
        ->whereRaw(DB::raw('FROM_UNIXTIME(date, \'%Y %D %M %h:%i\') not in (\'' . implode('\',\'', $data) . '\')'))
        ->get();
```